# How to express a python variable in a SQLITE3 statement

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created the following functions to create a table call `user`.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime


def create_connection(db_file):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return connection
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(e)
    return None


def create_table(connection, sql_table):
    cursor = connection.cursor() 
    with connection:
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql_table) 
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)


def insert_user(connection, date, username):
    cursor = connection.cursor() 
    with connection:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?)",(date, username))


database = "test.db"

user_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
                    date      TEXT    NOT NULL,
                    username  TEXT    NOT NULL
             ); """

conn = create_connection(database)
create_table(conn, user_table)
date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
username = 'user1'
insert_user(conn, date, username)
```

I would like to make the function `insert_user` more general. I would like to be able to pass `user` into this function and not have to explicitly write `user` in

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?)",(date, username))
```

Similarly, I would like to avoid explicitly writing `user` in

```
user_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
```

Rather I would like to have a variable having the value of `user` and passing that variable into this statement.

How should I amend my code? Thanks.

Comment: There's no special sqlite syntax for this, like there is with value parameters. You just have to use normal python string formatting. Or use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#Python).